# My cat lets me pet her then runs away and meows

Tags: cats

So I got a new cat recently and he was sort of a stray. He’s warmed up to me a lot and I can pick him up to sit on my lap. He will purr as I pet him and lay on his back so I can access his tummy. After about two minutes of this he will run away and sit on the stairs. He then precedes to call out to me meowing for me like he wants more pets but he just ran away from me? Help me understand, why is he behaving this way?

Comment: Our cat does the same thing, it seems she prefers some specific places in the house where she wants to be petted. Also, at specific times of the day. The morning ritual after breakfast is for her to lead one of us to the couch in the tv room to be petted. I stopped wondering and just comply.